# Nilpotent matrices in $M(n, \mathbb R)$ form a closed subset of $M(n,\mathbb R)$.

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, continuity

The set of all nilpotent matrices in $M(n, \mathbb R)$ (the space of all n by n matrices with entries from $\mathbb R$) is a closed subset of $M(n,\mathbb R)$.

The map $f_k: M(n, \mathbb R)\to M(n, \mathbb R)$ defined by $f_k(A)=A^k$ is continuous for every $k\in \mathbb N$.

$f_k^{-1}(0)$ is a closed set in $M(n, \mathbb R)$ and is actually the set of all matrices $A$ for which $A^k=0$, the zero matrix.

Now, I am stuck in showing that the union $\cup_{k=1}^\infty f_k^{-1}(0)$ is a closed set (because an infinite union of closed sets need not be closed).

Any hints on this? Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is well known(and proved many times on this site) that if $A$ is nilpotent in $M(n,\mathbb R)$ then $A^{n}=0$. Hence, you can characterize nilpotent matrices as $\{A : A^{n}=0\}$ which is clearly closed.

Comment: Did you mean that $A^{n^2}=0$? That's a good hint. Somehow I didn't think of that. Thank you so much.

Comment: @Koro The only eigen value of a nilpotent matrix is $0$. So the characteristic polynomial is $p(c)=c^{n}$ and Cayley-Hamilton Theorem shows that $A^{n}=0$. We don't need $A^{n^{2}}$.

Comment: Yes, you are right +1. Thank you so much. :)